# Using std::get as parameter for std::transform

Tags: c++, std

I'm likely missing something obvious here - why can't I use std::get in this way?

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> some_map;
    std::set<int> set_of_ints;
    std::transform( 
        some_map.begin(), 
        some_map.end(), 
        std::inserter( set_of_ints, set_of_ints.begin() ), 
        std::get<0> );
    return 0;
}
```

The compilers I tried were VS2010 as well as whatever Ideone.com uses for C++14 (some recent GCC?). Here's the output from the latter:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:17:28: error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::map<int, double>::iterator, std::map<int, double>::iterator, std::insert_iterator<std::set<int> >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   std::get<0, int, double> );
                            ^
prog.cpp:17:28: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4152:5: note: template<class _IIter, class _OIter, class _UnaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation)
     transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4152:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:17:28: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_UnaryOperation'
   std::get<0, int, double> );
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
                 from prog.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4189:5: note: template<class _IIter1, class _IIter2, class _OIter, class _BinaryOperation> _OIter std::transform(_IIter1, _IIter1, _IIter2, _OIter, _BinaryOperation)
     transform(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4189:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:17:28: note:   candidate expects 5 arguments, 4 provided
   std::get<0, int, double> );
```

Comment: `std::get<0>` is overloaded, so that's probably causing issues of which one to use.

Comment: One thing you could do is have a little `selectFirst` functor: `auto selectFirst = [](const auto &t) {return t.first;};`. Theoretically, this could be generalized with a macro `SELECT_MEMBER(name)`. Pre-C++14, you'd have to write out the whole functor without the lambda's help.

Comment: @chris, you should post that as an answer. I was initially skeptical, but then I remembered that a generalized lambda is a class type, not merely another overloaded function. So I guess it should work

Comment: I'm already using a lambda as a workaround, but it would have been much more elegant the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot decided which of the two following overloads to use.

```
int std::get<0, int, double>(const std::tuple<int, double>&)
int std::get<0, int, double>(const std::pair<int, double>&)
```

I don't see any way to make the compiler pick one or the other.

You may have to use a lambda or define a `T1 pair_first<T1, T2>(const std::pair<T1, T2>&)` function and then pass `pair_first` instead.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. I wrote a quick "my_get" (which was a reimplemented simple std::get), which then compiled, and then I added the declaration for a tuple overload and then the problem appeared again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `std::get<0>` with one of these:

```
[](       std:: pair<const int, double>  &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
// or
[](       decltype( *some_map.begin() )  &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
// or
[](       decltype(some_map)::value_type &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
// or cast to a function pointer
(const int & (*)(std::pair<const int,double> &)) std::get<0,const int,double>
```

Tested on clang 3.5.0. This forces it to use `std::get` for `pair`, not `tuple`.

Also, maybe you should be `const` in front of each of them, like this:

```
[]( const std:: pair<const int, double>  &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
// or
[]( const decltype( *some_map.begin() )  &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
// or
[]( const decltype(some_map)::value_type &x){return std:: get<0>(x);}
```

(Actually, I think the middle one, `decltype( *some_map.begin() )`, will automatically do the right const-ness for us.)

The cast-to-function-pointer was a bit awkward to get right, one has to get all the types *exactly* right.

Finally, inspired by @chris, here's a C++14 solution (with some perfect forwarding if you want to copy and paste this into other code):

```
[](auto&& x){return std:: get<0>(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));}
```

Comment: In pre-C++14, I'd probably write the function object type @chris mentioned: `template<int N> struct get_fot { template<typename T> auto operator() (T&& t) -> decltype(std::get<N>(std::forward<T>(t))) { return std::get<N>(std::forward<T>(t)); } };`